# EC2 instances launched via Terraform do not pass the status checks or have insufficient data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I use **Terraform** to launch 6 new m3.medium EC2 instances via different Auto Scaling Groups.

4 out of 6 have state: `running` but status_check: `Insufficient data` or `1/2 checks passed`. Basically only 2 launch correctly.

It seems really strange behaviour and I was wondering if anyone else encountered it.

Does it have to do with some limit of this type in specific region/AZ ?

Any pointer would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If your account is over a limit or there is insufficient hardware available, an instance ID will not be assigned -- the launch request will be denied outright.  So... that shouldn't be it.  Under the Actions drop-down, there's a way to view the console output from the instances. It may or may not work in this situation, but it's worth trying.

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at the system log for the instance and seeing if that reveals anything. We spin up in the order of 600 instances a day for testing environments and we get the odd few that don't come up properly for some odd reason and occasionally it feels like there's patterns (there aren't but the brain does love to search for them). I think the biggest thing that gets us (and shows on the system log) is systemd bringing things up in the wrong order and then the network never properly initialising. In your case though shouldn't the ASG replace the failed instances?

Comment: Do they all use the same machine image?

Comment: AWS does status check in every 60 seconds , please refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html and its not that your instances doesn't launch properly it might take some time to become healthy or have sufficient data for the health checks. if also launch instances using terraform and it takes some time them to become healthy. let me know if it is still showing the same status ?

Comment: I managed to cause a similar looking state when I first used Terraform to create instances. My issue was that I had incorrectly mounted some devices, causing the instance to be unbootable. Two bits of info would be useful: Your terraform code used for creating these instances, and whether you can access the instances via ssh.

Comment: @Bram, not they use different AMIs

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful comments, they pointed me in the right direction...So, all the flawed instances have these lines in their System Log. 
EXT3-fs: sda1: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (240).
EXT2-fs: sda1: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (240).
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,1)

Comment: I noticed that the flawed instances have 'paravirtual' as virtualisation type. Their images came from snapshots which were copied from another region. But I was not specifying the kernel-id during the copy. I am doing it from scratch and report back.

Comment: Check here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UserProvidedKernels.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console#Paravirtual_instances